# Build an array with powershell from json file

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have a json file that I would like to export or convert in csv or table format

My json source file is like this :

```
[
   {
      "host_display_name" : "DCWKS10",
      "host_groups" : [
         "Windows",
         "WINDOWS"
      ],
      "next_check" : 1698741835,
      "notes" : "",
      "notes_expanded" : "",
      "notes_url" : "",
      "notes_url_expanded" : "",
      "notification_interval" : 0.0,
      "notification_period" : "TP",
      "notifications_enabled" : 1,
      "obsess_over_service" : 1,
      "peer_key" : "7215e",
      "peer_name" : "Nagios",
      "percent_state_change" : 0.0,
      "perf_data" : "'E:\\ Used Space'=1475.08Gb;1474.56;1556.48;0.00;1638.40",
      "plugin_output" : "E:\\ - total: 1638.40 Gb - used: 1475.08 Gb (90%) - free 163.32 Gb (10%)",
      "process_performance_data" : 1,
      "retry_interval" : 1.0,
      "scheduled_downtime_depth" : 0,
      "state" : 1,
      "state_order" : 1,
      "state_type" : 1
   },
   {
      "host_display_name" : "DCWKS50",
      "host_groups" : [
         "Windows",
         "WINDOWS"
      ],
      "next_check" : 1698741896,
      "notes" : "",
      "notes_expanded" : "",
      "notes_url" : "",
      "notes_url_expanded" : "",
      "notification_interval" : 0.0,
      "notification_period" : "TP",
      "notifications_enabled" : 1,
      "obsess_over_service" : 1,
      "peer_key" : "7215e",
      "peer_name" : "Nagios",
      "percent_state_change" : 0.0,
      "perf_data" : "C=86.15;106.73;106.73;0;106.73 ",
      "plugin_output" : "CRITICAL - Disk D: 24.75 Gb (1.7%) Free",
      "process_performance_data" : 1,
      "retry_interval" : 1.0,
      "scheduled_downtime_depth" : 0,
      "state" : 2,
      "state_order" : 4,
      "state_type" : 1
   }
]
```

I have all variables $jsonObj.host_display_name, $jsonObj.host_groups .... but I don't know how to build an array formatted like this :

| host_display_name | host_groups |
| --- | --- |
| DCWKS10 | WINDOWS |
| DCWKS50 | WINDOWS |

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can make use of PowerShell's `ConvertFrom-Json` commandlet and Format-Table:

```bash
# Import the file contents and convert from Json to a PowerShell object.
$JsonData = Get-Content "source.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

# Select the headings you want, and format as a table
$JsonData | Select-Object host_display_name,host_groups | Format-Table
```

Comment: Nice, but note that unless you know the JSON file to contain a complete document on _each line_ that requires line-by-line parsing, it is much more efficient to use `Get-Content`'s `-Raw` switch to read the file _as a whole_ (`Get-Content -Raw ... | ConvertFrom-Json`)

Answer (score 1):

There is already an accepted answer.  I want to add an answer that generates a csv file.  A csv file will be more useful for downstream processing of the data.

ConvertFrom-JSON is part of the solution.  The next step after that is to convert the result into an array of custom objects.  This can be converted into csv, or into just about any data structure you want.

```
Get-content source.json |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    % { [pscustomobject] $_} |
    Select-Object host_display_name, host groups |
    Export-Csv Result.csv
```